# Compare two files field by field in Unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have two very large files in Unix each containing say 5 columns but millions of lines.

Ex :

File 1:
abc|def|ghk|ijk|lmn
....
...

File2 :
abc|def|ghk|ijk|123
...
...

My task is to compare the two large files and find out the differing columns and rows . For instance the output would be :
Column-no Row-no File1-word File2-word.

Ex :

5 1 lmn 123

The files are really large . I have heard awk is the fastest way to do file parsing in Unix. Since the output can't wait for too long.

Can this be done using awk?

Comment: Yes, it can be done with `awk` — though reading from two files concurrently is hard but saving all the input from one file and then using that while reading the second is a normal mode of operation for `awk` scripts.  What did you try, and where did you run into problems?  If you can use Perl or Python, you'd find it easier to avoid slurping the whole of one file into memory.

Comment: Even if I use Perl I atleast  have to slurp one file in memory right ? And then use that data structure to compare the second file

Comment: No; using Perl, you'd read one line from file 1 and one line from file 2 and then compare those lines, and print the differences; rinse and repeat.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler obviously you can do that in awk too with a `getline < file2` for every line read from file1. I'm not saying that's the best approach of course, just that it's do-able. Subhayan - edit your question to include concise, testable sample input (e.g. a couple of files of 4 or 5 rows and 4 or 5 columns each) and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paste/awk` solution

```
$ paste -d'|' file1 file2 | 
  awk -F'|' '{w=NF/2; 
              for(i=1;i<=w;i++) 
                 if($i!=$(i+w)) printf "%d %d %s %s", NR,i,$i,$(i+w); 
              print ""}'

1 5 lmn 123
```

I changed the order, it makes more sense to me to print the line number first then field number, however you can change it easily...

Once paste matches lines from two files go over field of the first half (first file) and compare with the second half (second file) and print the differences.  `awk` has the implicit loop to over all records (lines).  I haven't tested this with large files but for `awk` part it doesn't matter (record by record).  I'm not sure how eager `paste` is but I doubt it will blink.

Comment: I am not too proficient with awk . Can you please explain how this is done ?Also the process would work efficiently even in case of very large files

Comment: @SubhayanBhattacharya: The `paste` command puts a copy of line 1 from file1 on the same line as line 1 from file2, separated by a `|` (because of the `-d'|'`).  The `awk` command then works through the fields, comparing and printing when necessary.  If there are 5 fields in `file1`, there are 10 in the input line; `w` = 5; it compares `$1 with `$6`, `$2` with `$7`, etc, reporting diffs.